# Jigsaw puzzle resize function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to resize the jigsaw puzzle pieces on window resize event using the function as given below. But the puzzle pieces does not get resized on window resize event.

I have to reload the game to resize the puzzle pieces.

I want puzzle pieces should be resized on small screen without reloading the page.

Also the puzzle should retain its previous state on window resize event.

```
function resizeView() {
    var cv1 = self.ce.cv;
    cv1.width = document.getElementById('main-game').clientWidth-10, cv1.height = document.getElementById('main-game').clientHeight - 10;
    self.ce.redraw();
    if (Cevent.isTouchDevice) {
        Util.fullScreen()
    }
}
resizeView();
Util.addEvent(window, "resize", resizeView);
```

Any help will be appreciated !!!